# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getNumThingsCaught() from the type Fisher

Tags: java, types, static

```
public class Fisher { 
 public static int LIMIT = 10; // max # of fish that can be caught 
 private int numThingsCaught = 0;


 public int getNumThingsCaught() { return numThingsCaught; } 

}
```

This is my second class

```
public class Fish { 
 public boolean isDesirableTo(Fisher f) { 
  if (Fisher.getNumThingsCaught() < Fisher.LIMIT)
  return true;
  return false; 
 }
}
```

I am using eclipse and Fisher.getNumThingsCaught() is underlined, when i hover over to see the error the message says: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getNumThingsCaught() from the type Fisher" How can I change my code in my !//Fish//! class to make this code work?

Comment: Please look to the right.

Comment: Using `f.getNumThingsCaught()` instead.

Comment: Side note: generally `if (condition) return true; else return false;` can be written as `return condition;`.

Comment: Before you posted this, did you search for other questions about static references and non-static methods?  There may have been an answer there just waiting for you to discover it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either change `Fisher.getNumThingsCaught()` to `f.getNumThingsCaught()` because `f` is a reference to a `Fisher` object, or you can make that method static (which is not what you want)

So it will look like:

```
if (f.getNumThingsCaught() < Fisher.LIMIT)
     return true;
return false;
```

Also another programming tip. When you define a static variable straight away, consider making it `final` as well. Because I assume you do not want the `LIMIT` variable to change.

Answer (score 0):

In this piece of code: `Fisher.getNumThingsCaught()` Fisher is the name of the class, not reference to the object. Since `getNumThingsCaught` method is not static, you need to call it on object instance.

Solution: just change it to `f.getNumThingsCaught()`

Answer (score 0):

In the Fish class, you need a reference to a Fisher instance. You can do this by:

```
public class Fish { 
 Fisher fisher = null;
 public boolean isDesirableTo(Fisher f) 
 { 
    fisher = new Fisher();
  if (fisher.getNumThingsCaught() < Fisher.LIMIT)
  {
     return true;
  }
     return false; 
  }
 }

if (f.getNumThingsCaught() < Fisher.LIMIT)
     return true;
return false;
```

Add the final modifier to 'LIMIT' to ensure it cannot be overwritten.